# Remove items from an array in order until matching item is found

Tags: javascript

I have an array of items

```
const test = [
  {
    id: '1',
  },
  {
    id: 'a',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
  },
  {
    id: '5',
  },
  {
    id: 'c',
  },
  {
    id: '7',
  },
];
```

These objects are always going to be in the same order. I'd like to be able to remove all items in order from the start until a specific `id` is reached.

I thought I could do this by just looping through until one is found and then pushing the items coming after that to a separate array:

```
let skippedArray = []

let skipUntilIndex = undefined

test.forEach((item, i) => {
  if(item.id === 'b') {
    skipUntilIndex = i
  }
  if(skipUntilIndex && i >= skipUntilIndex) {
    skippedArray.push(item)
  }
})

// [
//   {
//     id: 'b',
//   },
//   {
//     id: '5',
//   },
//   {
//     id: 'c',
//   },
//   {
//     id: '7',
//   },
// ]
console.log(skippedArray)
```

But this seems pretty dirty. Is there a better way to achieve this? I don't mind using lodash or similar libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) methods, by `findIndex` you can find the index of target item in the array and with `slice` you can make a subArray of your original Array.

```js
const data = [ { id: '1', }, { id: 'a', }, { id: '3', }, { id: 'b', }, { id: '5', }, { id: 'c', }, { id: '7', }, ];

const getSkippedItems = (id)=> {
    const index = data.findIndex(v => v.id == id);
    return index > -1 ? data.slice(index) : [];
}

const skippedArr = getSkippedItems('b');
console.log(skippedArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to filter out all items until our desired id is reached.

We'll only create the output array once we find the required id, then push remaining items into it.

```js
const test = [ { id: '1' }, { id: 'a' }, { id: '3' }, { id: 'b' }, { id: '5' }, { id: 'c' }, { id: '7' } ];
 
const result = test.reduce((output, item) => { 
    if (!output && item.id === 'b') output = [];
    if (output) output.push(item);
    return output;
}, null);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a closure over a flag and if found filter the rest by found.

```js
const
    removeUntil = (id, found) => o => found ||= o.id === id,
    test = [{ id: '1' }, { id: 'a' }, { id: '3' }, { id: 'b' }, { id: '5' }, { id: 'c' }, { id: '7' }],
    result = test.filter(removeUntil('b'));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `forEach` and `splice`

```js
let arr = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}];
let marker;

arr.forEach((item,index) => {
    if (item.id == 3) {
        marker = index;     
    };
});

arr.splice(0, marker);

console.log(arr); // [{id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}]
```